# How to push arraylist each data to array in php

Tags: php, arraylist, silverstripe

```
$set = new ArrayList;
foreach($ordersList  as $order) {

   $Customer1 = $order->Customer1()->Age;
   $Customer2 = $order->Customer2()->Age;
   $Customer3 = $order->Customer3()->Age;

   $set->push($Customer1);
   $set->push($Customer2);
   $set->push($Customer3);

   $set1=array();
   debug::show($set);
   $set1= $set->toArray();

}
```

This is my source code. And this will retrieve only first records data only. Can any one explain how to retrive each and every records data in orderlist.

Comment: Refering to the comment on the answer. If the foreach loops only once , then you have issue how you filter the $ordersList, how do you query that? . That order > 3 customer relation is weird for me but probably not in the scope of the question :)

Comment: Dmax my solution didn't worked for you that means what @OlliTyynelä  is saying is correct.